# How to include plugin dependencies in JavaExec task classpath?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, javafx-11

I am using JavaExec tasks to run different classes, but whenever I try to run one of the tasks using `gradle <task>`, I get an error saying `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`.

If I just set `mainClassName='exercise1.Cards'` or whatever other className, running `gradle run` works completely fine. I'm guessing that the JavaFX classes are not found when running classes with JavaExec and I'm wondering how I can include them.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

task runExercise1(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'exercise1.Cards'
}

task runExercise2(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'exercise2.InvestmentCalculator'
}

task runExercise3(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'exercise3.PointCircle'
}

task runExercise4(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'exercise4.OccurrenceHistogram'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org.openjfx.javafxplugin` [plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin) manages for you a few things.

When you add to your build file:

```
javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}
```

the plugin [translates](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/openjfx/gradle/tasks/ExecTask.java#L62) that into something like:

```
run {
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = ['--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                   '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls']
    }
}
```

However, if you create a new `JavaExec` task, it seems the plugin doesn't process it.

Given the error you have posted:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing

it is clear that a possible fix is to do exactly what the plugin does and add the expected jvm args when using modular dependencies.

So this should work:

```
task runExercise1(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    jvmArgs = ['--module-path', classpath.asPath, 
               '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls' ]
    main = 'exercise1.Cards'
}
```

Alternatively you could create a launcher class that doesn't extend from `Application`, as that will bypass the modular check (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing/52654791#52654791)).

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // optionally process args to select class to run
        Cards.main(args);
    }
}
```

Then you could add your task, and even uses runtime arguments to select the main class to run from the launcher.

```
task runExercise1(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'exercise1.Launcher'
    args 'exercise1' // <-- optionally select class to run
}
```