# jaxws not compatible with javafx modules?

Tags: java, javafx, jax-ws

I have an java project with javafx and jaxws. Here a small snippelt from my gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:4.0.0'
}

javafx {
    version = "19"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

task runClient(type: JavaExec) {
    description = 'Run Client'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    jvmArgs = ['--module-path', classpath.asPath, '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml']
    main = 'ClientMain'
}
```

I set this jvmArgs because of [How to include plugin dependencies in JavaExec task classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795891/how-to-include-plugin-dependencies-in-javaexec-task-classpath/54796482#54796482).  I don't actually use modules otherwise in my project.

I now get the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module format not recognized: C:\Users\MyName\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.xml.ws\release-documentation\4.0.0\5eb09d77be092684546352a35f315423d67e044b\release-documentation-4.0.0-docbook.zip
```

Without javafx or jaxws everything is working. Only together there seems to be problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong dependency for jaxws for your purposes.  The difference in distributions is explained here:

- [What's the difference between jaxws-ri and jaxws-rt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401358/whats-the-difference-between-jaxws-ri-and-jaxws-rt)

`jaxws-ri` contains zipped documentation which should not be part of a modular distribution.

These are [dependencies you should be using](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-jax-ws/) (maven format, you will need to translate to gradle format):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Additional background info**

jaxws reference implementations are now maintained via the Eclipse foundation as jakarta XML services as part of [Eclipse Metro](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws).

The code should also use the `jakarta` package namespace as shown in the [jakarta documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-jax-ws/4.0.0/docs/ch03.html).

This would also apply to [module names](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.xml.ws/module-summary.html) if you provide a module-info.